# How does the compiler go through a class?

Tags: c++, compilation, forward-declaration, function-prototypes

So this is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class simpleClass
{
public:
    int var;

    simpleClass(int value)
    {
        var = value;
        memberFunc(var);  
    }

    void memberFunc(int var);
};



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    simpleClass(10);
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine. Will not run because I haven't defined memberFunc but it compiles fine. Now I remove the memberFunc from inside the class and put it outside.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class simpleClass
{
public:
    int var;

    simpleClass(int value)
    {
        var = value;
        memberFunc(var);  
    }

    //void memberFunc(int var);
};

void memberFunc(int var);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    simpleClass(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And for obvious reasons this doesn't compiler.
Now I move the prototype to the top of the class.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void memberFunc(int var);

class simpleClass
{
public:
    int var;

    simpleClass(int value)
    {
        var = value;
        memberFunc(var);  
    }

    //void memberFunc(int var);
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    simpleClass(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And of course this compiles.

Now here's my question.

- In the first case it compiled fine because I had declared the function inside the class.
- Second case was a compiler error, because the function declaration was 'after' the class definition. So compiler didn't know about the function when it was compiling the constructor. Fine.
- Third case, compiler is happy because it found the prototype ahead of the class declaration.

Now the question is, why in the first case it compiled?
Because the member class declaration was ***after*** the constructor. So how did the compiler know about the function declaration? Because the compiler is supposed to be going through the code sequentially.

Would someone explain if there is a certain procedure for compiling a class?

Thank you.

Comment: Classes are considered completely defined within their own member function bodies, it doesn't matter if the member declarations occur after they have been used.

Comment: This may not be historically accurate but the way I think about it is to assume that C++ class declarations were originally intended to contain only member *declarations*, with all the actual definitions like  `void simpleClass::memberFunc( int a ) { }` occurring after the class declaration has closed.  Defining a function in full *inside* the class declaration is, I guess, a shorthand for those two steps---so the compiler goes through the whole class declaration looking only for declarations,  then passes through again to pick up the definitions.

Comment: Names defined in the class are in scope in all member functions of the class. OTOH, namespace-scope names must be declared before their use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler goes through the complete class declaration twice: once just treating everything as a declaration, and then again to pick up any method definitions.

Comment: thank you. This is what I wanted to know. Is there any reference that explains this mechanism? Is it part of the standard?

Answer (score 3):

If you define class member functions inline, the semantics are as if your class definition only contained member function declarations and the definitions followed immediately after the class definition. In other words,

```
struct Foo
{
    int & f() { return n; }
    int n;
};
```

is parsed as:

```
struct Foo
{
    int & f();
    int n;
};

inline int & Foo::f() { return n; }
```

In particular, within member function bodies the class is always complete and completely defined.